# Custom Control VS Dynamic TemplateField checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I work on a custom server control that contains two grids with dynamic templatefield checkbox , the 1st one binded by SqlDataSource, the 2nd grid filled with selected rows in the 1st grid, 
all is clear, the 2nd grid filled appropriately  but when a button(out of the custom control) click event fired  the grid disappear ,  Second and what is important is how to save state of the checkbox while after postback I must create the field and bind the grid ?

I appreciate your direct answers .

for Template field :

```
class CheckBoxTemplateHandler:ITemplate  
{  
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)  
    {  
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();  
        cb.ID = "CB";  
        //cb.EnableViewState = true;  

        cb.AutoPostBack = true;  
        cb.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.cb_DataBinding);  
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Dynamic_Method);  
                    container.Controls.Add(cb);  

    }  
    protected void Dynamic_Method(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  

        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)  
        {  

            ((CheckBox)sender).Text = "Selected";  




        }  

    }  
    private void cb_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        // Get the checkbox control to bind the value. The checkbox control  
        // is contained in the object that raised the DataBinding   
        // event (the sender parameter).  
        CheckBox l = (CheckBox)sender;  

        // Get the GridViewRow object that contains the checkbox control.   
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;  


        // Get the field value from the GridViewRow object and   
        // assign it to the Text property of the checkbox control.  
        l.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "price").ToString();  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override all Control LifeCycle events (rebind gridview),I think it's a hard topic for 
lot of developer !

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind in Pre_Init.  The problem about loosing the selected value of the checkbox should go away, too.

Comment: this is a custom server control , I tried to override this.OnInit,this.OnLoad ... no way . In addition after any postback fired from any other component out of the control (in the page) all templatefields disappear . How can I rebind it if the Control.Page.On_Pre_Init fired ?